# On Private-Beta and User-Selection

Tags: support, superuser, private-beta

According to [Podcast #60](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/podcast-60/), Super User will be going into Private-Beta "Sometime in July." I'm curious how the SO-Team picks users to participate in the Private-Beta. Is the selection based on community-activity, reputation, question-answer ratio, or good old-fashion nepotism?

#### Update:

> "Now that we’ve got a logo and color scheme, the superuser.com private beta should begin sometime the month, and any Stack Overflow or Server Fault user with reputation of 200 or more is invited!"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've read something where Jeff said that any user with a reputation of 200 or over on SO or SF could take part in the beta.

**EDIT: found the link**

[This](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/logo-contest-winner-for-superusercom/) blog post mentions it at the very end.

Comment: "Now that we’ve got a logo and color scheme, the superuser.com private beta should begin sometime the month, and any Stack Overflow or Server Fault user with reputation of 200 or more is invited!"

Answer (score 3):

I would imagine that they tend to select those who happen to be in the top ranks on sites like StackOverflow and ServerFault (hey, maybe here? Maybe maybe maybe?). I think overall it is better to have a selection of users who are already familiar with the mechanisms and can help find some real problems than just opening it up to any user who may not have the experience working with it (as I understand the idea of the beta is to find problems).

Comment: There's no hope for me on SO (Yet! I'm almost to 1/10th Skeets rep). Perhaps if they pick from some of the top users here I might find a glimmer of sunshine :)